# ASP.NET MVC : method not found when two controllers has the same method name

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am writing an ASP.NET MVC app. I have two controllers, `Controller1` and `Controller2`. I have a method called `SearchBySSN` in my `Controller1`. I am calling this method via Ajax from the view:

```
$.ajax(
     {
         type: "POST",
         data: model,
         headers: {
             "RequestVerificationToken":
                 $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
         },
         url: '@Url.Action("SearchBySSN", "Controller1")',
         success: function (result) {

         },
         error: OnError
     });
```

My method is like this

```
[HttpPost("SearchBySSN")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ClientWebError(IsPartial = true)]
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchBySSN(string SSN)
{
}
```

When I created a method with the same name in `Controller2`, I try to call the method in controller1 and thrown an error that the method can not be found.

If I change the name of the method, it works.

Is it possible to have two controllers with the same method name?

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is possible. The problem is your route.

You defined the route as `SearchBySSN` in your `HTTPPost` attribute and I assume you did the same thing in your second controller.

This results in you binding the function to the route `<HOST>/SearchBySSN` for both and that does not work.

Do you have default routes defined? Should look similar to this in your `Startup.cs/Program.cs`:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default","{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } 
        );
```

You don't need to set the route manually in your attribute again. So just remove it.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ClientWebError(IsPartial = true)]
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchBySSN(string SSN)
{
}
```

Now it should be available at `/Controller1/SearchBySSN` and `/Controller2/SearchBySSN`

Comment: I solved it putting router in the controler
    [Route("Controller1")]